Арифметика указателей и массив символов
char arr[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
cout << &arr << endl;
cout << &arr + 1 << endl;

Почему адрес второго элемента находится на +3 байта? Разве не должно быть +1?

Ну так что такое arr? массив из трех char.
Что такое &arr+1? Следующий за ним массив из трех char. Где он в памяти располагается? На расстоянии трех char, т.е. трех байт...
Чтоб на 1 байт сместиться, надо адрес символа рассматривать...
cout << (void*)(&arr[0] + 1) << endl;


Но если &arr - адрес первого символа, то почему &arr + 1 уже указывает на другой массив? Почему именно массив, если его нет?

@IlyaQwerty Указывает на адрес за концом массива. Если бы у вас был массив массивов, то указывал бы на второй массив. Суть-то в том, что +1 смещает на размер указанного типа - не на размер чара, а на размер массива.

@IlyaQwerty &arr и (преобразованный в указатель) arr имеют одно и то же значение (адрес первого элемента сопадает с адресом всего массива), но разные типы, поэтому + сдвигает их на разное число байт.

@HolyBlackCat, получается, в первом случае у нас тип char[3], а во втором char*?
